# Question about Local field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\hat K$ be a local field and let $\hat L$ be an abelian extension of $\hat K$ with Galois group $G.$ we know that there is a number field $L$ and a place $\frak P$ of $L$ such that $\hat L=L_{\frak P}.$ Denote by  $E=\prod_{\sigma \in G}\sigma(L).$

How to prove that :$\hat L=E_{\frak P}.$ ?

**Edit** I found this statement in  Serge_Lang Algebraic Number Theory :
[image]

i don't understand why $K_v=L$ ?

Comment: This is hard to follow. What do you mean by $E_\mathfrak{P}$? $\mathfrak{P}$ is not an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis $E_{\frak P}$ = the completion of $E$ at $\frak P$ and  $\frak P$ is an ideal od $O_L$

Comment: @AlexYoucis I found it in Serge Lang Algebraic Number Theory Second Editi page 221